# Link retains underline even after text-decoration:none

Tags: css, reactjs, gatsby

I am making a navbar for a website made via GatsbyJS. I am attempting to style the links in the navbar such that they do not have an underline.

I have already set the link to not have any text decoration--when I inspect the element in my browser, it even shows the "text-decoration: none" property. I have also confirmed that my CSS is influencing the object--I can change the color of the text, for example, it is only the text-decoration which I cannot influence.

CSS:

```
.nav {
  background: #fd8;
}

.nav ul {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav ul li a {
  color: #221;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

html + js:

```
...
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import styles from "./navbar.module.css"

...

      <nav className={styles.nav}>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }} to="/about">
              About
            </Link>
          </li>
```

EDIT: the inline styling with textDecoration was a product of some fiddling I was doing prior to posting this question and was not present until recently. Removing it has no effect on the issue.

Rendered HTML by request:

```
<nav class="navbar-module--nav--25Dcz">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="/#">About</a>
    </li>
    ...
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: This strikes me as a purely CSS issue. Please post rendered HTML.

Comment: And have you looked for `border-bottom` on the anchor or list item?

Comment: I have added the rendered HTML. Also, I have confirmed that the element does not possess a bottom border--I can add one and it shows up alongside the underlining.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have discovered that the errant underline was actually a 1px box-shadow, probably from some global style I can't find associated with the Gatsby Typography plugin.

Comment: Similar problem here though the property I had to reset was `background-image` which was a linear gradient that ended up looking line an underline.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `.nav` you want to select a class by that. And as I see, in your html,

`nav` (`<nav...`) is a tag with a class `navbar-module--nav--25Dcz`

So if you change your CSS to:

(Remove the period character `.` from `.nav`)

```
nav {...}
nav ul {...}
nav ul li {...}
nav ul li a {...}
```

It should work fine.

Also, take a look at Styled Components: https://www.styled-components.com/ which let you write CSS in JS and use similar features from preprocessors like Less and SASS.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I believe I selected the appropriate class in my HTML/React:
`<nav className={styles.nav}>`

In any case, i attempted this solution and removed the "."s from my css, and the problem persists.

Comment: Have you tried adding `text-decoration: none` on `nav ul li a:hover {...}` or `nav ul li a:focus {...}` or `nav ul li a:active {...}`?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're using a class selector (`.nav`) when you should be using a tag name selector instead. Changing to `nav ul li a{text-decoration:none}` should fix your issue. If that doesn't work, then you probably have some CSS with higher precedence somewhere that is overriding it.

Answer (score 0):

So for those still searching for an answer. **It's really a BUG.** At least with <ul>, <li> tags and their nesting. There's just one bypass, and even that has a bit of a limitation. So here's a sample with a fixed (removed) underline and it contains notes also on what to add, what to avoid.

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/keep-remove-underline-from-nested-li-item?file=index.html [working text decoration removal]

**the solution is:**

1. need to use inline-block for <ul>, set vertical top align and 100% width
2. avoid to use white-space nowrap

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything to remove it, then after reading this I remembered that I added what in the link https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/typography-js/

Icones was underlined, anything that will be  was underlined 
nothing worked until I removed that.

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why, but when I referenced a class that was LESS specific I was able to get the text decoration to go away with text-decoration none. So if you have a less specific wrapper class try targeting the links with that

```css
.wrapper a {
   text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the global a tag or be specific, and after text decoration, add `!important`. That will override any default styling that gatsby is imposing.

```
.nav ul li a {
  color: #221;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
```